# Math in C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to convert this code to C#, but Math.pow in C# doesn't work.

The code I know that works, but with js:

```
var levelCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.12, level));
```

I have been trying to convert it to C#, but with not help.

Comment: "can't get it work" is not a question.  Please post specific errors, etc.

Comment: The function is called [`Mathf.Pow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Pow.html), also, caseing is important in C#, you can't do `Mathf.pow(`

Comment: Please note that you've now asked 5 questions *all* of which have a negative score. I strongly suggest you read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ thoroughly... if you keep asking poorly-received questions, you will be automatically banned from asking more.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That wouldn't work with 1.12, which is a `double` rather than a `float`. Unless the OP really wants `float`, they probably want `Math.Floor` and `Math.Pow` using the regular `System.Math` class.

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to convert this code to csharp, but Math.pow in csharp, dont
>   work..

here is a `C#` version:

```
var levelCost = Math.Floor(200 * Math.Pow(1.12, level));
```

the only difference is the casing i.e `C#` follows [PascalCasing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) convention.